# Number of rows and columns are taken from the command arguments; if missing, set default to 3 (rows) and 4 (columns). Using Nestedloop **** **** ****

Tags: bash

I keep getting an operand error and how would u fix it the code is below

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
then
m=3
n=4
else
m=$1
n=$2
fi

printf "\n"
printf "\n"

m_1=$(( m-1 ))
n_1=$(( n-1 ))

for (( i=0; i<$m; i++ )); do      <--- error:operand expected error token is <
    for (( j=0; j<$n; j++ )); do
       printf "*"
    done
    printf "\n"
done

printf "\n"
printf "\n"
```

Comment: Also, I'd remove the double quotes from `"$#"` as, here too, it is interpreted to be an integer, not a string.

Comment: The use of `-eq` is correct, so you did that right.

Comment: @Roadowl With `(( ))` you can work with integers with `<` and without `$`. `for (( i=0; i<4; i++ )); do echo "i=$i"; done` works fine.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Thanks, I never use this construct myself (use the old-school way myself).

Comment: So actually the problem was using `$m` instead of plain `m` here. Same for `$n`.

Comment: Did you add comment in your file like `<--- my comment --->`?  You need `# comment like this`. Code (without the comment) works for me.

Comment: when dealing with syntax issues consider running your code through [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) for assistance

Comment: @WalterA no there is no comments in the file, i just added it on here so yall can know where to error was. and yeah it works when i do something like bash star.bash 3 9 but when i dont put anything after .bash it give me the error. im trying to make it so if i dont put anything the default will be 3 4

Comment: You could just use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html): `m=${1:-3}; n=${2:-4}`

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works fine for me, so my problem was not solving an error but reproducing/finding an error. I came up with a script that shows a similar error message:

```
# Make sure m is empty for this test
unset m
for (( i=0; i<$m; i++ )); do
   echo  3
done
```

In the special syntax `((...))` you can write `$m` as `m`, and you won't see an error.

Looking at your code again, I can see 2 ways the error can be caused:

```
# 1. Your script is called with an empty first argument   
./my_script.sh "" 4
# Perhaps after calling another program that should return a number,
# but sometimes return en empty string:
./my_script.sh "$(wc -l 2>/dev/null < non_existing_file)" 3

# 2. Your script is called with 1 argument
./my_script.sh 3
./my_script.sh: line xx: ((: j<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<")
./my_script.sh: line xx: ((: j<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<")
./my_script.sh: line xx: ((: j<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<")
```

In this case the error occurs with the `for (( j=0; j<$n; j++ )); do` line.

Make sure you don't start your script with an empty first argument and try the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

m=${1:-3}
n=${2:-4}

printf "\n\n"

for (( i=0; i<m; i++ )); do
   for (( j=0; j<n; j++ )); do
      printf "*"
   done
   printf "\n"
done

printf "\n\n"
```